# Express Checkout - Go straight to credit card payment?

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

I have a simple e-commerce site using Paypal.  At the moment, it has a single button at the end of the process which takes the user to Paypal.  At this point, the user has to either pay directly through paypal or by using their credit card.

I would like to replace the single button with one that takes them to the regular Paypal process and a few others (credit card logos), which send the user to the credit card payment form on Paypal (cutting out the selection stage).

Is there anyway to do this?

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I know it is been six months but maybe someone will come to this page for an answer:

In express-checkout api you can set landing page for credit card with this:
`LANDINGPAGE=Billing`

Here is the [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/)